# How do I add an own program to the "open with" menu

Tags: unity, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is “open with…” in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71359/where-is-open-with-in-nautilus)

After installing oneiric I'm not able to add my own scripts to the "open with" menu in ubuntu (I've been using lucid up to now). Adding the scripts to /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin my applications still don't show up in the "open with" menu.