# Change default application to open file in Oneiric

Tags: nautilus, text-editor, default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is “open with…” in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71359/where-is-open-with-in-nautilus)

In Oneiric, the "Open with other application..." menu in Nautilus only allows to select one of the predefined applications.

There is no option for a custom application any more. Can you suggest how to open a file with a custom command?

For example, I want to change the default text editor from gedit to Komodo Edit which, even if installed, does not appear in the list of available applications (it's installed locally). Previously, I could just say "open with custom command", digit `komodo` and it worked.

How can I do this in Oneiric?