# How to specify a not listed application in Nautilus' »open with« dialogue

Tags: nautilus, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is “open with…” in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71359/where-is-open-with-in-nautilus)

Back In Nautilus 2 when using the »open with« dialogue there was always a field to specify manually a command to open the file.

Where is it in Nautilus 3? How can I use it now to open a file with my scripts or with application not providing a desktop-file like Vim, Emacs or something else? Please don't tell me I have to create desktop-files for these scripts or applications to do so!

Comment: Interesting. There seems to have been changes in how you decide what software should be used to open files. And you're right, I couldn't find an obvious way to add a command to that list. I would assume you'd need a desktop file for it with a statement to mark it as a "file opener", but that's just speculation.

Comment: Sure, you are right Jo. They want us now to create manually desktop files for each case in witch we want to open a file with a non listed application. Look at this bug report and please tell them, that they are on the wrong way! https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650284

Comment: Nobody has said anything about manually creating anything. All applications should provide desktop files. That's what they're for. For instance, if you install alacarte (menu editor used by default in Gnome 2), then it will provide you with a GUI to create desktop files. That's what it does. There are _lots_ of applications that provide you with a GUI to create desktop files. Why should applications provide these things and not scripts and CLI apps? If vim, nano and emacs do the same things that gedit does, why should they be treated differently?

Comment: I am not sure whether or not I got your point, Jo. Sure there are apps to create desktop files, but the desktop file is not the issue! I think a file manger should make me able to open a file with anything I like to. That's one of the basic functions of a file manager. If it does not provide this function, in my opinion it's useless. I think that programs like Emacs, Vim an so on, makes Linux as rich as it is. If Gnome becomes as closed as Windows or MacOS not enable the user to do what ever they want, to use even non GUI apps or bash-scripts form the GUI, what is it good for?

Comment: You can do that. But why should a user have to browse hundreds or thousands of files? It's much better to limit the selection to programs that can actually handle that file type in a meaningful way. Would you ever want to open a movie file with gcalctool, for instance? No. So why should it be displayed? It shouldn't. That's why the programs have to say that they can handle the file type. Nobody is refusing to let you open a file with the app you want, whether it's a GUI, CLI, webapp or anything else.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad - the big problem with that is how often Nautilus gets the type wrong, especially on non-local file systems.

Comment: I can't see that nautilus is offering me specific applications for the file type. I see always any desktop file laying in ~/.local/share/applications