# How to open php files on Eclipse PDT Indigo

Tags: 11.10, php, eclipse, extension, file-association

Since I have downloaded and installed the Eclipse PDT Indigo, I want to make it opens automatically files with .php extension.

Before Oneiric's release, simply right clicking on any .php file, selecting the Proprierties item, and entering "Open as" tab, gives the possibility to set an custom application command-line to open the file, but now it doesn't possible.

Because I downloaded the Eclipse's .tar.gz binaries and simply extracted to /usr/lib and created a symbolic link to /usr/bin, it doesn't appear on the list of applications supported, and I can't set a custom command-line, only find online an other.

So, I make a question: how do I make my Eclipse PDT opens automatically PHP files?

Tks for all.

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/71373/11736) on how to add eclipse to the Application list

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.

I solved it by using Ubuntu Tweak: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/;

The current version has a tab "Admins", and at the bottom there is "File Type Manager"; select category "all" and browse to php script: there you can add to link to `/usr/bin/eclipse`.