# How I install drRacket?

Tags: software-installation

I installed drRacket in Ubuntu by downloading the source file [from here](http://pre.racket-lang.org/installers/). I then ran

```
sudo ./racket-5.2.1-bin-i386-linux-ubuntu-karmic.sh
```

after making it an exe file so the file is in the usr/racket/bin/drracket

1. I want to run it from command line without going to its directory
2. I cant make the drRacket to run the `.rkt` files by the "open with"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Add /usr/racket/bin to your PATH.**  If you use bash (which is the default for the terminal in Ubuntu), you would edit your `.bashrc` file to have the two lines:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/racket/bin:$PATH
   export PATH
   ```

   If your `.bashrc` already has a PATH setting, then you need to add /usr/racket/bin to it.  For example, I already have a PATH setting that looks like: `PATH=~/bin:$PATH`.  I would then change it to: `PATH=/usr/racket/bin:~/bin:$PATH`.  The colons act as separators while $PATH will include whatever your default environment PATH is.  Bash will look in the locations in the order listed, so actually I would probably prefer `PATH=~/bin:/usr/racket/bin:$PATH` so that my personal scripts (which I put in ~/bin) would be picked over anything else.

   If you don't have a `.bashrc` in your home directory, make one using your favorite text editor with the two lines above.

   The modification won't take effect until you open a new terminal or you type `source .bashrc` in the current terminal.
2. **Add drRacket to the "open with" submenu of the right-click menu**.  I think you are probably using the default file manager, Nautilus.  I don't use that anymore but my understanding is that people have been having problems with this.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71359/where-is-open-with-in-nautilus) for a solution.

Answer (score 7):

Open *Terminal* and enter these commands to add the Racket PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plt/racket -y`

and install:

`sudo apt-get install racket -y`

You can run it by entering `drracket` or opening it in *Applications* menu.